# highCharts legends click event not working for type column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I want a click event on highChart legends, so I'm trying below options but those are not working.
$scope.highchartConfig is a config which I'm using with angular 1.x.
Also I'm using highChart version 4. Please help me on what I'm doing wrong and what workout I need to.

```
$scope.highchartConfig = {
    barGraph: {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                height: 300
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function(event) {
                            alert('TEST');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Quantity',
                data: [40, 25, 10, 15]
            },
            {
                name: 'Value',
                data: [60, 25, 20, 60]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

OR

```
$scope.highchartConfig = {
    barGraph: {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                height: 300
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function(event) {
                            alert('TEST');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Quantity',
                data: [40, 25, 10, 15]
            },
            {
                name: 'Value',
                data: [60, 25, 20, 60]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your template code as well

Comment: As such there is no template, refer below directive code:

return {
      restrict: 'EAC',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div></div>',
      scope: {
        config: '=',
        disableDataWatch: '='
      },
      link: link
    };

This is how I'm using directive in my HTML page:
<highchart config="highchartConfig.barGraph"></highchart>

Comment: Is the chart rendered? Are the columns drawn properly? Is the legend visible?

Comment: This is the example in their site https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-legenditemclick/

Comment: I have seen all examples which they have provided.

Comment: posting a jsfiddle of what you have done would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Mayur D, it seems that you have wrong options structure. Options for series, chart and plotOptions should be on the same level.